How can i call bootstrap react function in react that can not messs code?
in this code bootstrap provide code that i want to use as i can not repeat myself and also it not look good for making 2 thing again i use custom css also so way confusing so how can i make in function that call in that main log.
it provide function code in bootstrap.so i can i implement this thing in code that not be bad and hard code.
This is the basic table function
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';

function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Table striped bordered hover>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Username</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td colSpan={2}>Larry the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  );
}

export default BasicExample;

when i use this it need to be safer side so it not look messy and i dont have write thing again and again.
return (
    <>
      <div className="table">
        <div className="table-data">
        <Table className="addWorkOut">
          {/* <thead>
        <tr>   
        </tr>
      </thead> */}
          <tbody className="table-body">
            <tr className="workoutProperty">
              <td className="table-content">WorkOutDate</td>
              <td>
                <input type="date" name="workoutDate" />
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr className="workoutProperty">
              <td className="table-content">WorkOutType</td>
              <td>
                <select name="workoutTypeSelect">
                  <option value="">1</option>
                  <option value="">2</option>
                  <option value="">3</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td className="table-content">WorkOutName</td>
              <td>
                <select name="workoutNameSelect">
                  <option value="">1</option>
                  <option value="">2</option>
                  <option value="">3</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td className="table-content">Minutes</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="Minutes" />
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td className="table-content">Calculate Burnt</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="calculateBurnt" />
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td className="table-content">Start Time</td>
              <td>
                <input type="date" name="startTime" />
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td colSpan={4}>
              <Button className="btn1" variant="danger">
                Add Workout
              </Button>{" "}
              </td>
              
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </Table>


      <div className="table-result">
      <Table striped bordered hover className="addWorkOutResult">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th className="table-header">Date</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Minutes</th>
          <th>Calories Burnt</th>
          <th>Start Time</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>2024-04-27</td>
          <td>Cartlo</td>
          <td>Running</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>140</td>
          <td>6:30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2024-04-27</td>
          <td>Cartlo</td>
          <td>Running</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>140</td>
          <td>6:30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2024-04-27</td>
          <td>Cartlo</td>
          <td>Running</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>140</td>
          <td>6:30</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
     </Table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </>
);

How to call that function to other function that can be reusable one is for taking input and one is for output

Do you want to make a reusable table component in react

yes and also if react provide that function for table i want to do call in that main function Log() {} here
